# Reading in a text file efficiently

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, filereader

How would you make a method to read a text file in java, given that the text file has 20,000 rows. The first element of the row is a word and the rest 50 values are the corresponding word vector

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple [options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html), with the best choice depending on the specific considerations of your use case. The syntax of course depends on that choice. Some of the main options are [BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--), [Files.readAllLines(Path path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-), [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and [Files.newBufferedReader(Path path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-), or even external libraries such as LineIterator from Apache [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

Files.readAllLines may be the simplest option to implement and most straightforward to read. Files.newBufferedReader may be one of the more [efficient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).